# Adding a column with a count

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this :

```
d = {'device' : ['D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D2', 'D2', 'D2', 'D2', 'D2',],
     'interval' : ['Day 1', 'Day 1', 'Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 2', 'Day 2', 'Day 3', 'Day 3', 'Day 3', 'Day 3'],
     'data' : np.random.rand(10) }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.set_index(['device','interval'], inplace=True)
print(df)

                   data
device interval          
D1     Day 1     0.087297
       Day 1     0.849820
       Day 1     0.577146
       Day 2     0.027389
       Day 2     0.469095
D2     Day 2     0.685370
       Day 3     0.988979
       Day 3     0.092372
       Day 3     0.578315
       Day 3     0.052130
```

I'd like to add a column that counts the number of inverval occurances per device.  For example, I would expect the result to look like this.

```
                   data    count
device interval          
D1     Day 1     0.087297    1
       Day 1     0.849820    2
       Day 1     0.577146    3
       Day 2     0.027389    1
       Day 2     0.469095    2
D2     Day 2     0.685370    1
       Day 3     0.988979    1
       Day 3     0.092372    2
       Day 3     0.578315    3
       Day 3     0.052130    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a count column by [`group`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)ing on the index levels and using [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to apply a `lambda` that calls [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html) on each grouping with params `method='dense' and`ascending=False`:

```
In [15]:
df['count'] = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='dense', ascending=False))
df

Out[15]:
                     data  count
device interval                 
D1     Day 1     0.442826      1
       Day 1     0.307261      2
       Day 1     0.040172      3
       Day 2     0.489025      1
       Day 2     0.210805      2
D2     Day 2     0.335703      1
       Day 3     0.659730      1
       Day 3     0.658278      2
       Day 3     0.296398      3
       Day 3     0.218484      4
```

Comment: This works perfectly for the example. In my real dataset I have more columns so I get `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 20, placement implies 1`  Any hints?

Comment: You may need to access a specific column in your case, try `df['count'] = df.groupby(level=[0,1])['data'].transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='dense', ascending=False))`

Comment: Works wonderfully.  Just have to be careful there's no duplicate data in the 'data' column.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question, but I've since run into an issue.  Occasionally my data will have repeats.  Because this method relies on ranking the unique values per index the locations where the repeated value exists will have the same count.  This can produce an Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! when using the count as in index later.  Any thoughts on how to avoid the possibility of repeat counts?

Comment: Do you want to keep these duplicates or drop them? you can drop them using `drop_duplictes` one way would be to `reset_index`, then pass a list of the columns that you want the dupes to be dropped `df.drop_duplicates(subset=list_of_cols)` or remove the duplicates from the index `df.index = df.index.drop_duplicates`, however, if this doesn't work you'll need to post a new question with data, code, desired output and any errors

Comment: Thanks ... probably best to ask a new question.  With my data there should only be 3 data per Device/Interval.  In the case there are 4 it's not automatic to sort out which is the incorrect one.  When the value of 'data' is common between 2 of the 4 I get something like [1, 1, 2, 3] rather than [1, 2, 3, 4].  I'm looking to throw an error to have the user sort it out manually.  I'll work up an example and ask a new question.

Comment: from what I can tell scipy.stats.rankdata method=ordinal is what I'm looking for, but not an option in dataframe.rank

Comment: try `method='first'`

Comment: it maybe worth asking if the docs can be updated so that they follow scipy docs at [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

Comment: I'll submit an issue

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether there is any better way to do it in pandas, but in plain python you may add a key to your `d` dict as:

```
d['count'] = [d['interval'][:i].count(day)+1 for i, day in enumerate(d['interval'])]
```

which will add `count` key to your dictionary with value as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```